# Postgres choosing BTREE instead of BRIN index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

I'm running Postgres 9.5 and am playing around with BRIN indexes.  I have a fact table with about 150 million rows and I'm trying to get PG to use a BRIN index.  My query is:

```
select sum(transaction_amt), 
       sum (total_amt) 
from fact_transaction 
where transaction_date_key between 20170101 and 20170201
```

I created both a BTREE index and a BRIN index (default pages_per_range value of 128) on column transaction_date_key (the above query is referring to January to February 2017).  I would have thought that PG would choose to use the BRIN index however it goes with the BTREE index.  Here is the explain plan:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/uPI

I then deleted the BTREE index, did a vacuum / analyze on the the table, and re-ran the query and it *did* choose the BRIN index however the run time was considerably longer:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/5VXi

In fact my tests were all faster when using the BTREE index rather than the BRIN index.  I thought it was supposed to be the opposite?

I'd prefer to use the BRIN index because of its smaller size however I can't seem to get PG to use it.

Note: I loaded the data, starting from January 2017 through to June 2017 (defined via transaction_date_key) as I read that physical table ordering makes a difference when using BRIN indexes.

Does anyone know why PG is choosing to use the BTREE index and why BRIN is so much slower in my case?

Comment: Can you show us the the output of `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, timing)` instead of "just" `explain (analyze)`

Comment: Sure - running them now.

Comment: B-Tree and BRIN:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/S3Zp

BRIN only:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/Z1A5

Comment: I haven't used BRIN indices myself, but my understanding is that they only work well if your data is ordered on disk in a way that matches your query and BRIN index. Have you tried to run CLUSTER on your table?

Comment: Sorry no go there.  I tried to cluster the table however it looks like clustering is not possible using a BRIN type index.  I typed `CLUSTER fact_transaction USING i_fact_transaction_transaction_date_key;` but it returns `ERROR: cannot cluster on index "i_fact_transaction_transaction_date_key" because access method does not support clustering
SQL state: 0A000`

Comment: `BRIN`'s advantage comes in its size, not from its speed -- *Because a BRIN index is very small, scanning the index adds little overhead compared to a sequential scan* -- I don't think it's ever meant to be comparable to BTREE (in performance). If BTREE is possible (its size is allowable for the application) it's superior to BRIN in speed. -- At least for those queries, where only a small subset is expected to be selected. When almost all of the table is selected, a BRIN might perform better (in those situations -- without BRIN -- a sequential scan would be chosen anyway).

Comment: Thank You @Laurenz Albe, changing the pages_per_range to 64 made the query run much faster using the BRIN index.  I do have a follow up question but I'll create a new post for that, (regarding an efficient way to choose the pages_per_range size.)

Comment: Are you SURE that your data's indexed value and physical location are in the same order.. IE, All rows were definitely inserted in the order as if they were ordered by this column?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like the BRIN index scan is not very selective – it returns 30 million rows, all of which have to be re-checked, which is where the time is spent.

That probably means that `transaction_date_key` is not well correlated with the physical location of the rows in the table.

A [BRIN index works](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/brin-intro.html) by “lumping together” ranges of table blocks (how many can be configured with the storage parameter `pages_per_range`, whose default value is 128). The maximum and minimum of the indexed value for eatch range of blocks is stored.

So a lot of block ranges in your table contain `transaction_date_key` between `20170101` and `20170201`, and all of these blocks have to be scanned to compute the query result.

I see two options to improve the situation:

- Lower the `pages_per_range` storage parameter. That will make the index bigger, but it will reduce the number of “false positive” blocks.
- Cluster the table on the `transaction_date_key` attribute. As you have found out, that requires (at least temporarily) a B-tree index on the column.