# Postgres BRIN pages_per_range calculation

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

this is a follow-up question to my previous post regarding BRIN indexes in Postgres 9.5 [Postgres choosing BTREE instead of BRIN index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098803/postgres-choosing-btree-instead-of-brin-index/42112578#42112578).

Is there an *intelligent* way to calculate what the:

```
 pages_per_range
```

value should be should set to when creating a BRIN index?  I have a fact table that will grow by about 1 million rows every day and I want to place a BRIN index on the date_key column (integer).  A typical value would be 20170801 (August, 1 2017).

From my previous post I found that setting it to half the default value ( I set it to 64) led to a huge speed increase in query time.   I can choose an arbitrary value (like 64) but wanted to know if anyone had another (more intelligent) method?

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: Curious to hear this answer, too! I'm going to try a few different values for a BRIN index on a timestamp and see  what works best.

Comment: I think that there are no "silver bullet" number. It depends on the queries you want to do over the table. If you select a large fraction of the table in each query, then a bigger **can be** the `pages_per_range` (because you don't need granularity and the index will be smaller...) but if you queries selects a small subset of rows, a smaller value will fit much better (with a cost of more space used by the index).